# Try Upsert before Committing

Tags: apex, visualforce

Suppose I have a Save function which saves a visualforce page which has changes to both the parent record and child records on a single page.  The upserts may fail if the parent record has errors or if the child record has errors (namely if either trip validation rules for their respective objects).  My question is: is there a way to see if all the upserts will succeed *before* we commit the changes in the database?  Otherwise there is weird behavior of seeing an error and thinking that all changes failed when actually part of the changes succeeded.

Here's the snippet of relevant code:

```
public PageReference onSave(){
    Try{
        list<Timeentry_Distribution__c> toUpdate = new list<Timeentry_Distribution__c>();
        for(map<string,Timeentry_Distribution__c> o:mapPD.values()){
            toUpdate.addAll(o.values());
        }
       upsert toUpdate; //Upsert Grandchild records
       upsert objTimesheets.Timesheet_Entries__r; //Upsert Child records
       upsert objTimesheets; //Upsert parent records 
       return (new ApexPages.StandardController(objTimesheets)).view();
    }
    Catch (Exception ex){
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use Database.upsert() instead along with savepoint and rollback methods available. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use Database.Upsert() instead of upsert which return Database.UpsertResult as response.

```
Database.UpsertResult [] objUpsertResult = Database.upsert(lstRecords);
```

﻿

You can always use it with setSavepoint() when working with such scenario; child and parent record updates to in a single transaction and rollback() to any saved point.

You can refer the [help doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) for different database methods available